# $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ compact, convex that does not contain $0$.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, compactness, inner-products

Let $\langle\cdot , \cdot \rangle$ be an inner product in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $U$ is compact, convex and $0 \notin U$. Show that we can find a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and a number $\delta > 0 $ such that $\delta \leq \langle  u , v \rangle$ for all $u \in U$.

My attempt:
Since $0 \notin U$ then $0 \in \mathbb{R}^m - U$. Since $U$ is compact, it is closed, and then $\mathbb{R}^m - U$ is open. Then there is $\delta > 0$ such that the open ball $B(0, \delta) \subset \mathbb{R}^m - U$. But then we can find a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $v \in B(0, \delta)$ but $v \notin U$. And I do not know how to proceed from here.

Any help would be great.

Comment: When you say "compact" what metric are you referring to?

Comment: Do you mean $|\langle u,v\rangle|$? Because without absolute value this looks clearly false. For example if $U$ contains both $u$ and $-u$ for some vector $u$.

Comment: @Zima For the metric induced by the inner product, would be the most natural.

Comment: @Mark, I have it stated as I wrote, $\delta \leq \langle  u , v \rangle$. $U$ is also convex

Comment: @P.G I see you just added that $U$ has to be convex. This makes a difference, as now $U$ can't contain both $u$ and $-u$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : since $U$ is compact, it admits a point $p$ closest to $0$. Consider $v=p$. Is it possible to find $q \in U$ with $\langle q,p \rangle < \langle p, p \rangle =: \delta$ ? (Think of a small perturbation $p + \epsilon (q-p)$)